# Infinite subset of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

I want to show that if the set $A$ is an infinite subset of natural numbers $N$, then $\text{card}(A)=\text{card}(N)$. To do so, it suffices to find an injective function $f:N\rightarrow A$.

One natural way to construct $f$ is as follows: we assign to $f(1)$ the smallest element of $A$. Then we omit the smallest element of $A$ and we assign to $f(2)$ the smallest element of the remaining numbers and so on.

I do not want to use the well ordering principle. I argue as follows. I assign to $f(1)$ an arbitary element of A like $a_1$.Then I remove $a_1$ from $A$ and assign to $f(2)$ an arbitrary element of $A/a_1$. Since $A$ is infinite, I can assign to $f(n)$ a number from $A$ for any $n$ because $A$ never gets empty.

Do I need to use the axiom of choice here??

Comment: To do it as you want to do, you do need the axiom of choice (or at least the axiom of countable choice, I am not sure). If you want to avoid the axiom of choice, always take the minimum element of A instead of an arbitrary element of A. Upd: i've now read the second paragraph and seen that you want to avoid doing this, so disregard my second sentence.

Comment: To the OP: by "well-ordering principle" do you mean the statement that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, or the statement that *every set can be* well-ordered? The latter is equivalent to choice, but is also irrelevant here: to run the standard argument all you need is that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, which has nothing to do with choice.

Comment: I mean $N$ is well-ordered.

Answer (score 3):

No. You don't need the axiom of choice. $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered without relying on the axiom of choice, indeed it is a defining property of $\Bbb N$: it is the *unique* non-empty linear order that is well-ordered, without a maximal, and every element has a successor.

The thing about the term "arbitrary" is that you're effectively hiding a choice function from the non-empty subsets of $A$ (or at least the co-finite subsets). So the question is why such a function exists, and in order to prove this you'll need to resort to proving that $A$ is either countable, or at least there is an injection from $\Bbb N$ into $A$.

So you run into a slight circularity. Of course, the axiom of choice might be used for the argument a priori, and then removed in the a postriori by arguing "actually since there is a well-ordering of $A$ as a subset of $\Bbb N$ here's a choice function".

Comment: Note that they explicitly describe the choice-free argument and say they don't want to use it.

Comment: In particular, per their comment their "well-ordering principle" is the well-orderedness of $\mathbb{N}$, rather than the full well-ordering theorem. So the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered without choice doesn't address their question - they want to avoid using the well-orderedness of $\mathbb{N}$ at all. (Of course they *shouldn't*, but ...)

Comment: Yes, but if you say "I need a choice function to choose a rational from each open interval in $\Bbb R$" that's one thing. But you can actually show that such a choice function exists, and run with that one. To wit, the one arising from the well-ordering principle. Saying "pick an arbitrary" means "pick a choice function". Just because you don't want to appeal to AC, doesn't mean that none exist.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying you're not actually answering the question they're asking: they specifically want to know if *the argument they have in mind* requires choice, which it does, even though the result doesn't. (And it's not AC they don't want to appeal to, they don't want to appeal to the well-orderedness of $\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: The argument requires a choice function to run the recursion against "arbitrary". You can use supercompact cardinals to argue that there is a choice function because you have an elementary embedding of whatever. It doesn't change the fact that ultimately the set of choice functions is non-empty already in ZF.

Comment: My point is that ultimately, AC is only used to prove that a certain set is non-empty. You can invoke it, yes. But the fact of the matter is that the set is non-empty regardless of AC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do need some amount of the axiom of choice to run the argument you're describing **(although of course the *result* doesn't need choice at all, and there's absolutely no reason to avoid using the well-orderedness of $\mathbb{N}$)**. Specifically, you're using [**dependent choice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice).

---

It's worth noting that the following statement is not provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without choice) alone:

> If $X$ is infinite, then there is an injection $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$.

(Sets not admitting an injection from $\mathbb{N}$, or equivalently sets with no non-surjective self-injection, are called *Dedekind-finite*; in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ every Dedekind-finite set is finite, but this is not provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone. In fact, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set of real numbers!)

So if you want to prove "Every infinite set of natural numbers admits a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$" without using the axiom of choice, you need to at some point use something particular about the natural numbers - such as their well-orderedness. Given that the well-orderedness of $\mathbb{N}$ is basically its most fundamental property, this isn't exactly a high cost.

Comment: Can we use this argument: Since $\mathbb N$ is countable, its elements can be enumerated as $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ and since $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ is an infinite subset, it follows that $A=\{a_{n_k}:k\in \mathbb N\}$ and hence define a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $A$ by $k\to a_{n_k}$?

Comment: @Koro The "it follows" is hiding exactly what we're trying to prove.